# How to set default value of select in HTML?

Tags: html, html-select

I've made a select in html that looks like this `<select name='select' id='select'><option value='val1'>Val1</option><option value='val2'>Val2</option></select>`. Is there a way to set the default value of `select` to something like "pick a value"? Not as an option, but just the text of the select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `selected` attribute within the option to select a default response. If you add the option `disabled` and `hidden` then this will be an invalid option.

```
<select name='select' id='select'>
    <option value='val1' selected disabled hidden>Choose option</option>
    <option value='val1'>Val1</option>
    <option value='val2'>Val2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have another option that doesn't have a value and give it the option of selected?

```
 <select name='select' id='select'>
      <option value='val1'>Val1</option>
      <option value='val2'>Val2</option>
      <option value='' selected>Choose Value</option>
 </select>
```

Then in your php or whatever server side test to make sure you aren't accepting an empty value, or use js to not allow the form to submit if the value is blank?